# Laravel dd(storage_path('app/public/file_name')) gives different results in Linus and Window respectively

Tags: php, laravel

Result in windows

```
drive_name\project_name\storage\app/public/file_name/
```

Result in Linux

```
drive_name\project_name\storage\app\public\file_name\
```

Difference Path Slashes to different platform with "/" and "\".

How to handle this???

Comment: Whats the problem; where is the application gonna run I assume on the Linux server not Windows. There is no answer to your question; we do not know your goal. If you use pure Laravel ehm. [flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/) you do not need to care about this very issue.

Comment: i am developing this laravel project in windows xampp server and ubuntu as well for testing and i know this project will be hosted to linux server but testing at localhost is also make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `realpath()` function to get the absolute path.
This will replace "/" with "\" with respect to the operating system.

**Therefore**

Just replace `dd(storage_path('app/public/file_name'))`

with

```
dd(realpath(storage_path('app/public/file_name')))
```